# Drawing Ellipse and Half-Ellipse in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, circles, tikz-graphdrawing

how can I draw some ellipses being "cut" by a half-ellipse like in the image (and also being able to write some labels on the ellipses)?

And also, what should I do if I want to have a circle/ellipse within a circle/ellipse (n times) and want to do this "cut" by a half-ellipse? So far, inspired by some answers here, I can only do the following to draw the circles:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, fill=white] (a) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=4cm, draw, fill=white] (b) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=2cm, draw, fill=white] (c) {$T_{0}$};

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = H2}] (150:2.5) arc (150:60:2.5cm); 

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = T1 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ T2}] (90:1.5) arc (90:-90:1.5cm); 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you!

[image: Ellipses and Revision]

Comment: Note that an ellipse is nothing more than just an unevenly scalled circle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the mathematical or logical meaning of your diagram (e.g. does the red ellipse need to be tangent with the black ellipse?), so I can't redraw it accurately. However, the following code draw two full ellipses and one partial ellipse.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\draw (0,3) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\draw (-3,1.5) +(60:1cm and 2cm) arc (60:-240:1cm and 2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, changing the coordinates, the `1cm`s and the `2cm`, and adding the text is your job. I think you can do  it now.

Answer (score 2):

This produces something similar to your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {-1,1}
  {\draw[name path=elli-\Z] (0,\Y) circle[x radius=3,y radius=0.9];}
 \draw[red,name path=elli-3] (0,1.9) arc(35:-220:1.6 and 2.4) 
  node[pos=0.8,left]{$\mathsf{K}*\mathsf{A}$}
  (0,1.9) arc(35:40:1.6 and 2.4);
 \draw[blue,name path=elli-4] (0,1.9) arc(145:400:1.6 and 2.4) node[pos=0.8,right]{$\mathsf{K}*\mathsf{B}$}
  (0,1.9) arc(145:140:1.6 and 2.4);
 \path[name intersections={of=elli-1 and elli-3,by={i1,i2,i3,i4}}]  (i4) node[above
 right]{$\mathsf{H}_1$};
 \path[name intersections={of=elli-3 and elli-4,by={i5,i6}}]  (i6) 
 node[left]{$\mathsf{T}_1$} node[right,xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]{$\mathsf{T}_2$};
 \path[name intersections={of=elli-1 and elli-4,by={i7,i8,i9,i10}}]  (i10) 
 node[below right,xshift=1em]{$\mathsf{K}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    % Red half oval
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(0,0)}, local bounding box = redScope]
        \clip(1,-1)rectangle(-1,0.7);
        \draw[red] (0,0) circle [x radius=6mm, y radius=1cm];
    \end{scope}
    \node[red] at (redScope.west) {$\mathsf{K}*\mathsf{A}$};
    % Blue half oval
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}, local bounding box = blueScope]
        \clip(1,-1)rectangle(-1,0.7);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) circle [x radius=6mm, y radius=1cm];
    \end{scope}
    \node[blue] at (blueScope.east) {$\mathsf{K}*\mathsf{B}$};
    % Upper black oval
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,0.25)}]
        \draw[](0,0) circle [x radius=1.075cm, y radius=3mm];
        \node[blue] at (blueScope.east) {$\mathsf{K}*\mathsf{B}$};
    \end{scope}
    % Lower black oval
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,-0.6)}]
        \draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1.075cm, y radius=4mm];
    \end{scope}
    %Inner labeling
    \node[black] at (redScope.south)[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$\mathsf{H_1}$};
    \node[black] at (redScope.south)[xshift= 0.5cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$\mathsf{T_1}$};
    \node[black] at (blueScope.south)[yshift=0.6cm] {$\mathsf{T_2}$};
    \node[black] at (blueScope.south east)[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.25cm] {$\mathsf{K}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```